# eu-west-1 AWS 'Could not fetch tags: An internal error has occurred'

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

eu-west-1 (Irland) AWS 'Could not fetch tags: An internal error has occurred'
It was warning 3-4 hour ago.

In Frankfurt (eu-central-1) this is working...

Do You have the same issue?

My scripts (ansible) depends on the tags, so I wonder how often that happens and when this will be fixed...

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed this as well, contacted AWS, they're on it.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=652141&tstart=0 mentions this as well.

There's a tiny note on http://status.aws.amazon.com at "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Ireland)" (tab Europe).

I've never had this problem and I use AWS daily, so it's probably nothing to worry about (until it starts to happen more often ;))